# Where to register RegisterClientScriptBlock in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Where is the best part of asp.net page or code behind to register `RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "register".

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're talking about RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: @Bob ah well no wonder I was clueless.

Comment: sorry I missed to mention that I meant RegisterClientScriptBlock.

please remove the vote down!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bunch of options.

Register script includes in your `<head>` section or do inline `<script>` tags.  I prefer to have my scripts at the bottom of the page though.

You can also register it at the `Page` level in your `Page_Load` (or any other event) by calling `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and passing it the script you want.  Remember that if you do go with `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, you will need to make sure that you register the code with every page load so that is why I would recommend the `Page_Load` event if you want to use this method.

For example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddClientSideJavascript();
    // Do other stuff
}


private void AddClientSideJavascript()
{
    // Register some client script code
    Type someType = this.GetType();
    if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(someType, "TESTSCRIPT"))
    {
        string script = "function ShowAlert() { alert('Test'); }";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(someType, "TESTSCRIPT", script, true);
    }

    // Register more here... etc...
}
```

Just make sure you don't include it the portion of your `Page_Load` that is wrapped with the `if (!IsPostBack)` check or else your scripts will not get registered after any postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is - at any point within page_load.